# Iterate through dataframe for specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
**Name**         **Place**                 
Geranium          Paris                       
Geranium          Amsterdam              
Geranium          Copenhagen
Daffodil          Washington
Daffodil          Helsinki
Daffodil          Tokyo
Daffodil          Sydney
Carnations        Kiambu
Carnations        Athens
```

I want to find the least distance between a particular place, say Chicago, and the places listed in the dataframe where the flowers mentioned are grown.
The output would be something like this:

- Geranium - 1732.40 miles
- Daffodil - 563.78 miles
- Carnations - 3943.21 miles

Where I have found the distance between a specific given place and each place listed in the dataframe corresponding to "Carnations", and arrived at the least value.

I know how to calculate the distance using geopy. What I am unsure of is how to iterate over the dataframe, item by item for each flower, to find the least possible distance. The actual dataframe contains over 3000 rows.

Looking for any suggestions.

Comment: Take a look at pandas [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)  using the .min() function

Comment: It would be good if you could add your dataframe after you've got the distances for a particular place though